# How getScreenshotAs in chromedriver is implemented internally

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am exploring the getScreenshotAs method of Takesscreenshot interface in selenium webdriver. I wanted to understand how it is implemented internally in chromedriver class

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can refer https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/TakesScreenshot.html
Hopefully will help !!

Comment: Thanks for the info. I came to know that the internal implementation of any drivers is not visible explicitly.